# Why does 'this.count++' work the same as 'count.value++' in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Both of the following code snippets increments the counter correctly using the Vue3 composition API. I expect method 1 to work by doing
`count.value++`. But why does method 2 with `this.count++` work? Is there ever a situation where we would want to use method 2?

---

Method 1:

```js
<template>
  <button @click="inc">{{ count }}</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0);
    const inc = function () {
      count.value++;
    };

    return {
      inc,
      count,
    };
  },
};
```

---

Method 2:

```js
<template>
  <button @click="inc">{{ count }}</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0);
    const inc = function () {
      this.count++;
    };

    return {
      inc,
      count,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You really, really shouldn't be using `this` in `setup()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never us `this` in `setup()`!**

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-of-this

I assume it works as `setup()` acts like a constructor and you are using a `function` and not an arrow function, thus `this` probably points to the `setup()` function and `count` is part of it.